# python cmd2 using the first command that contains a hyphen

Tags: python, command-line-interface, cmd2

Using CMD2 CLI I want to create a command that has a hyphen in the first command.

```py
def do_command_something(self, args):
   print("command-something")
```

I want it to work as below

```
cmd> command-something
command-something
```

I have been looking for a while and can not come up with a way within the CMD2 framework to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyphen is not a valid character as an identifier in Python, so you cannot name a method with it directly in the class definition.

Instead, define the `do` method under a different name first, and then use `setattr` on the class object to give the method the desired name with a hyphen. You can delete the original name after that if you want:

```
import cmd2

class App(cmd2.Cmd):
    def do_command_something(self, args):
        print("command-something")

setattr(App, 'do_command-something', App.do_command_something)
del App.do_command_something
App().cmdloop()
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/HealthyConcernedRotation

Test run:

```
(Cmd) command-something
command-something
(Cmd) command_something
command_something is not a recognized command, alias, or macro
(Cmd)
```